# Definition of divergence operator

Tags: vector-analysis

There is the geometric definition of a divergence of a vertor field to be the following limit:

[image]

How does this definition turns out to be the del operator dot the vector field in cartesian coordinates?

Thanks,
Eran.

I tried the calculations for the $ z $ component of the field and got the integrals:

$ \int_{y-\frac{L}{2}}^{y+\frac{L}{2}}\int_{x-\frac{L}{2}}^{x+\frac{L}{2}}F_{z}(x,y,z+L)dxdy-\int_{y-\frac{L}{2}}^{y+\frac{L}{2}}\int_{x-\frac{L}{2}}^{x+\frac{L}{2}}F_{z}(x,y,z)dxdy= $

$ =\int_{y-\frac{L}{2}}^{y+\frac{L}{2}}\int_{x-\frac{L}{2}}^{x+\frac{L}{2}}[F_{z}(x,y,z+L)-F_{z}(x,y,z)]dxdy $

Where of course, $L$ goes to $0$.

What can I do next?

Comment: Have you considered, for example, the surface of a cube as the surface of integration?

Comment: I've tried a little bit, but I don't know what to do with the general vector field.

Comment: Are you able to write the vector field $F$ and the surface element $dA$ in terms of their cartesian components and the cartesian basis vectors?

Comment: I can write the field as $ F=(F_{x},F_{y},F_{z}) $, but what about $ dA $  ?

Comment: Yeah.  If you were using $\nabla$ directly instead, wouldn't you end up writing something in terms of partial derivatives of those components?  So those components seem like good things to start with.

Comment: For $dA$, using the surface of a cube means it will only have one component on each face.  For instance, the top face is $(0, 0, dx \, dy)$.

Comment: So I get a sum of integrals, what are my boundaries?

Comment: This is the surface of a cube, centered at the point at which you want to evaluate the divergence.  If you know the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of that point, you should be able to determine the bounds of each face.  The length of each face is arbitrary (pick some length $\ell$) and should go to zero as $V$ goes to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you're at this point, you need to approximate $F_z(x, y, z+L)$ in terms of $F_z(x, y, z)$ and $L$.

For instance, consider a Taylor series expansion:

$$F_z(x, y, z+L) = F_z(x, y, z) + L \left. \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z} \right|_{x, y, z} + \frac{1}{2} L^2 \left. \frac{\partial^2 F_z}{\partial z^2} \right|_{x, y, z} + O(L^3)$$

This lets you argue that the integral on the $z$-faces takes the form

$$\int_{x-L/2}^{x+L/2} \int_{y-L/2}^{y+L/2} L \left. \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z} \right|_{x, y, z} + O(L^2) \, dx \, dy$$

Use more Taylor expansions (on $x$ and $y$) to argue that, to lowest order in $L$, we get

$$\left. L^3 \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z} \right|_{x, y, z}$$

Of course, the volume of the cube is $L^3$, so when we divide and take the limit, we get

$$\lim_{L \to 0} \frac{1}{L^3} L^3 \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial z}$$

I trust you can repeat the process for the $F_x, F_y$ components?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The $x$ and $y$ Taylor expansions you are talking about allow us to compute the double integral?

Comment: Sorry, the notation is a little sloppy. Ultimately what you want to do is write $F_x, F_y, F_z$ each in terms of a Taylor expansion around the central point and in terms of the side length $L$.  In turn, this turns the integrals over $x, y, z$ into integrals over $L$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it. Only one last question:
Can I assume that the integrand is constant over a very small surface?

Comment: That's basically what we're doing with the Taylor expansion--showing that any terms that vary over the surface must become small in the limit $L \to 0$.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Of course. The integral form of divergence (or curl, or gradient) is very useful; if it's of interest to you, you can use the same procedure in spherical or cylindrical coordinates (instead of a perfect cube, you'll have to use pieces of spheres or cylinders), and this is convenient way to derive the divergence, gradient, and curl formulas for general coordinate systems.

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do this moment.